# standard method to get notfication from database on change/insertion

Tags: php, mysql

I am curently trying to make a chat application aimed at 1000-1500 users. What currently happens is once my webpage loads I make an ajax request every second to check if there is anything new in the database. I want to know if this is the standard practise or if there is a more efficient way to be notified by the server somehow when an insertion occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use WebSockets. Or at the very least AJAX polling. Firing a request every second from 1500 clients will most likely kill your server.

Look at http://socket.io/ if you are open to introduce something new to your stack. But there are PHP websocket solutions out there if you are limited to PHP.

Comment: Even if I use socket.io i will still be required to query my database ateast once a second per user to check for message updates. Would that also lead to problems as well?

Comment: The idea is to structure the application in another way then. You don't need to store the messages in the DB. Or at least you don't need to constantly read from it. Just push messages over WS directly to users when they arrive.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a standard method called [Polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29). Based on the number of clients this should be perfectly fine for a server with up-to-date hard-ware (do `HEAD` requests via `AJAX` that indicate the status via `HTTP status` code).

The other alternative - as pointed out by Jan - is called [Pushing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).

- Pros: Involves a lot less requests to the server.
- Cons: Requires technology that may or may not be provided by your client's browser.

In case you'll opt for the second approach, take a look into [Server-Sent Events](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) (W3C draft).

> This specification defines an API for opening an HTTP connection for receiving push notifications from a server in the form of DOM events. The API is designed such that it can be extended to work with other push notification schemes such as Push SMS.