# How to fire a request after an entry into the db?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have developed a news and activity feed in one of my project, it works on a very basic principles and to auto update the news feed I fire an ajax request after every 30 seconds which appears to be the least effective way of auto updating the feed. The load on server becomes heavy, and sometimes unexpected things happen when other ajax requests get fired.

So is there any way to fire a request after an ebtry into db. You can see my whole code here http://www.techknowlogists.com/how-to-create-facebook-like-news-feed-with-php-and-jquery/

It is a tutorial I wrote but I want to improve it. Thanks

Comment: Not stricty a duplicate, but I think it will show you what to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578519/standard-method-to-get-notfication-from-database-on-change-insertion

Comment: You could consider node.js + socket.io for your backend in such an activity feed.

Comment: @x_maras node.js is a brilliant bit of kit, but IMO websockets is the obvious and best solution here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you cannot fire an event when a value is entered into a database. However, there is a better way to achieve what you are wanting using `websockets`. These are slightly more advanced that AJAX requests, but they will provide exactly what you want.

There are plenty of references for websockets all over the net. These are a few of them:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

http://www.davesite.com/html5-code-tutorials/html5_interactive_intro_html_5/websockets/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262543/what-are-good-resources-for-learning-html5-websocket

Comment: So does it means facebook is also using web sockets, the reason I asked this question is because sometime back I heard it from my colleague that we can set something on server level which will fire a request whenever after an insert query in db

Comment: @UmairAbid Yes, Facebook use websockets :-)

Comment: it appears to be something dependent on browsers, does all major browsers support socketing?

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, I know I asked some dumb questions but you tolerate them well :)

Comment: @UmairAbid It is a good question, I was going to ask the same thing a while ago, but managed to find the answer on SO. I was already aware of the answer but I didn't want to have to accept that I needed to learn yet another thing (websockets), but with the help of projects such as socket.io, it makes our life a lot easier :-)

Comment: exactly I was wondering how am I going to send notifications to users on runtime but I guess I have find my answer, thanks again